# Server side templating for node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, django-templates

I am creating a website using Node.js. Node.js server makes webservice call to get dynamic data and then embed the data in html templates to create final html for client. The data in mostly static on client side. I was considering Angular.js, but it seems that it will be overkill as users will not update the data on browser. Maintaining data bindings on client side are not required. So I am considering to use

- a templating engine like Swig or Jade for generating initial html
- angular.js only for the elements that user can update

Please advise if that is the right approach to go or if there is any better approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is undoubtedly the right approach.

Note that Jade can be used on the client-side as well (with the runtime), so you can avoid Angular.js completely (reducing the loading time) if you want to. But generally speaking you're doing the right thing here.

Comment: I am using this tech stack for the first time. So I was wanted to be sure. Thanks for your response.